# can't delete conditionally from xml using Java

Tags: java, xml

I've an xml file that I need to delete certain elements depending on the attribute value. the unconditional deletion works just fine but this won't:

```
NodeList nodes = doc.getElementsByTagName("host");
           Element d;
          for ( int i = 0; i < nodes.getLength(); i++ ) { 
           String state = nodes.item(i).getChildNodes().item(0).getAttributes().item(0).getTextContent();
           if("down".equals(state)){
              d= (Element) nodes.item(0);
             d.getParentNode().removeChild(d);
              System.out.println(state);
           } 
           }
```

Comment: When you say it doesn't work, what's the effect? No deletion? An exception?

Comment: it only deletes some of the elements that meet the conditions, at a time. It turns out I have to run the program several times for it to delete all the need to be deleted elements!!

Comment: What's the  (simplified) structure of your XML? What's the name of the attribute that has the `down` value? Are you sure it is always the first in the list?

Comment: Yes I'm sure, I did some checking, and it truns out it doesn't go through the hole loop, perhaps because it contains more than 60000 items, to start with.?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are a couple of problems with the code. The first is the line

```
String state = nodes.item(i).getChildNodes().item(0).getAttributes().item(0).getTextContent();
```

which assumes that 1) there are no text nodes between child elements, and 2) that the attribute looked for is always the first attribute in the list. This makes the code brittle and subject to failure if the format of the input document change.

The second problem is that while iterating over the node list, some of the members of the list are removed from their parent. The behavior of the list if detaching/removing children from their parent is not specified in the DOM API, why the effect could vary between implementations. Not sure if this is the case here, but I wouldn't depend on guessing.

I would suggest using XPath instead (much clearer and shorter). Something like this:

```
    XPath xp = XPathFactory.newInstance().newXPath();
    NodeList list = (NodeList) xp.evaluate("//node[*[@* = 'down']]", doc, XPathConstants.NODESET);
    for(int i=0; i < list.getLength(); ++i) {
        Node node = list.item(i);
        node.getParentNode().removeChild(node);
    }
```

The expression `//node[*[@* = 'down']]` selects all `<node>` elements that have a child element that has any attribute with value `down`.

Comment: this line doesn't find any element I printed the size and it's always 0:
(NodeList) xp.evaluate("//node[*[@* = 'down']]", doc, PathConstants.NODESET);

Comment: Ok, justvreplace node with host